# Getting Protected Content License Error while playing DRM Protected Video in Roku Brightscript

Tags: video-player, drm, roku, brightscript, widevine

[Code for Playing DRM Content in Roku] https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJlT5.png
[Output Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTBrS.png)

I want to play DRM Protected video in Roku, For that I had attached the code and the Error which I'm getting, I need WidevineBody as parameter to fire LicenseUrl to play the content ig. I had videoUrl, LicenseUrl. Can anyone suggest any solution how to get WidevineBody from Roku Player.

I didn't find any solution on how to get WidevineBody as response from VideoPlayer, If I use same API / DRM Content for other Languages/framework for playing video there videoPlayer will return WidevineBody the we will fire with LicenseUrl to play the content, but in Roku I didn't find any solution for how to get WidevineBody from Video Player.